# Get package.json path?

Tags: node.js

I want to make my file paths relative to the project root. I know `package.json` will be in the project root. Is there a good way to find the file path of package.json by searching up the file tree?

Answer (score 1):

The module [fs-finder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-finder) has a `lookUp()` method that should get you mostly there.